# How to get rid of these PPA

Tags: ppa

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I fix a 404 Error using a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-using-a-ppa)

How to get rid of these PPA?

```
Err http: //ppa.launchpad.net quantal/main Sources 404  Not Found
Err http:// ppa.launchpad.net quantal/main i386 Packages 404  Not Found
Ign http: //ppa.launchpad.net quantal/main Translation-en_US
Ign http: //ppa.launchpad.net quantal/main Translation-en
Ign http: //ppa.launchpad.net quantal/main Translation-en_US
Ign http: //ppa.launchpad.net quantal/main Translation-en
W: Failed to fetch http: //ppa.launchpad.net/deluge-team/ppa/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch http: //ppa.launchpad.net/deluge-team/ppa/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```